# Adding context menu to IE to execute my program

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, regedit

I wanted to know how can I add a new item to IE context menu (right click menu), so that the selected text from a website is copied, my winform application C# is opened and the text is pasted into a text box in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an entry to IE standard context menu to open your program. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open registry and go to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt
   ```
2. Create a new key, and set the name of key to the text you want displayed in the context menu as the name, for example: `Open My App`
3. Right click on `(Default)` and choose `Modify...` and set the value to path of an html file which will contains the command to open your application. For example: `C:\OpenMyApp.html`
4. Add a new `DWORD` value named `Context` and set it's value to hexadecimal `11` or decimal `17`. To see more options read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(v=vs.85).aspx). Also in documentations said to add binary but I tried `DWORD` instead and it worked. Also other extensions that I've seen use `DWORD`.
5. Use this content for your `C:\OpenMyApp.html`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function getSelectionText(w) {
           var text = "";
           if (w.getSelection) {
               text = w.getSelection().toString();
           } else if (w.document.selection && w.document.selection.type != "Control") {
               text = w.document.selection.createRange().text;
           }
           return text;
       }

       var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
       var selection = getSelectionText(parentwin);
       var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
       var commandtoRun = "C:\\MyApp.exe"; 
       oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"\""+selection+"\"","","open","1");
   </script>
   ```
6. Then it's enough to copy your application to `C:\MyApp.exe`. Your application should handle command line arguments by accepting `string[] args` as input parameters for `Main` entry point or using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Then it's enough to pass the argument to your form and show it on your text box.

For more information:

- [Adding Entries to the Standard Context Menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Browser Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm getting the error: This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action

Comment: @Graham The only file we are trying to run in above example, is 'C:\MyApp.exe' which will not cause such error. Check your file name and file extension and try again.

Comment: My file is C:\test2\blah.exe and blah.exe just creates another file so that I can see that it has done something.  When I run blah.exe on it's own it does as expected.

Comment: It's hard to guess what is the reason of such problem. If it can be [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post a new question about it :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei  From above Java script, can you put the alert showing the text selected from IE? so everytime we select text from IE, and rightclick menu, alert pop up.

Comment: @RaspiSurya Above solution adds a new menu item to context menu, called *Open My App*. By clicking on the *Open My App*, it will run your application. Instead of running the application you can run any script which you need, including showing an alert.

Comment: I have succeed adding the context menu, I just want to execute openmyapp.html from rightclick menu, and then show the selected text in alert. 
--------------

function getSelectionText(w) {
        var text = "";
        if (w.getSelection) {
            text = w.getSelection().toString();
        } 
  else if (w.document.selection && w.document.selection.type != "Control") {
            text = w.document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return text;
    }
 
alert(text);

where did I miss?

Comment: In which line of the code showing the passing parameter from IE to the var text?

Comment: `var selection = getSelectionText(parentwin);` In this line of code, `selection` is the selected text.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you very much! you are very good! it works!

Comment: @RezaAghaei one more thing Reza, How can I open my test.html site into the new tab / new browser via regedit? currently I just execute C:\qnavi.htm in REG_SZ.

Comment: @RaspiSurya I didn't tried, but if you create `var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");`, then `oShell.ShellExecute("http://www.google.com")` should open google in new tab/window of the browser.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I try to use your method to get the html class in IE browser. So i put code :
var title= document.getElementsByClassName("ttl");
var aNode = title[0];
alert(aNode);

but it doesnt work. Do you know why?

Comment: @RaspiSurya Make sure you are using the correct document object. For my example, I should use document object of the passed window, for example: `w.document.getElementsByClassName('something')`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei can you help to answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041265/get-external-website-url-using-external-javascript-in-ie-browser

Comment: @RaspiSurya Yes, I posted an answer for your question.